# Is there any way to use javascript variables and use them in Jinja?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I want to use my localStorage variable to set the starting class of my sidebar to wether it is collapsed or not making it preserve its state when refreshing or goint to the next link

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let isSidebarCollapsed = localStorage.getItem('sidebarCollapsed') === 'true';
  console.log(isSidebarCollapsed);

  if (isSidebarCollapsed) {
    $("#sidebar").addClass('collapse');
  } else {
    $("#sidebar").removeClass('collapse');
  }
  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
    // Toggle the collapse class on the sidebar
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass('collapse');
    
    isSidebarCollapsed = $("#sidebar").hasClass('collapse');
    // Update the local storage with the current state
    localStorage.setItem('sidebarCollapsed', isSidebarCollapsed);
    console.log(isSidebarCollapsed);
    document.cookie = `sidebarCollapsed=${isSidebarCollapsed};path=/`;
  });
});
```

In my sidebar it should be

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-main show {% if isSidebarCollapsed %}collapse{% endif %} sticky-top" style="height: auto; margin-top: 80px;">
```

I tried the above script to add the collapse class if it is not collapsed but it makes this blinking effect because the initial state of the sidebar class is not collapsed so everytime the page is refreshed it quickly switches from not collapsed to collapsed quickly
If I could use the javascript variable like the jinja templating it would be much easier

Comment: Could it be a solution to add the `collapse` class in the template and only remove it in the javascript if the variable is set in local storage?

That way the "blinking" should not happen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving it to to localstorage I saved the state into session.sidebar then added route to toggle the value of session sidebar and use ajax to access the route